# vuetify resize size e font component

Tags: components, vuetify.js

I need to reduce the size (height) of the text-input component and use less vertical separation space between them.
how can I do ?
I should fit 25 lines on one screen (h = 1024px)
how to set defaut font size?

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Can you please post what code you have tried so far.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask Please give more context, code, configurations files in order to help you accordingly. Thanks.